# Display students name and score in mathematics( even if they don t have a score )

Tags: mysql, sql

Student table: id, name, class
Score table: student_id, score, discipline
i tried:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
  ID int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(225),
  Class varchar(225)
  );

  CREATE TABLE SCORES(
  student_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES STUDENT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  Score int,
  Discipline varchar(225)
  );

Select distinct st.name   ,
                case when sc.discipline='Mathematics' then sc.score
                     else 'NO SCORE'
                end as Mathematics_score
from STUDENT st left join SCORES sc on st.id=sc.student_id   ;
```

result:

```
name               Mathematics_score
Liam                   NO SCORE
ANIA                   NO SCORE
ALEX                   NO SCORE
MAX                       7
MAX                    NO SCORE
ANIA                      9
ABC                    NO SCORE
```

What i need to change to show  just once a name if they have grade for mathematics. for example MAX has grade to mathematics and Biology and he appear twice in table
Thank you and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Select distinct st.name, Coalesce(sc.score,"No Score") as Mathematics_score
from STUDENT st left join SCORES sc 
    on st.id=sc.student_id and  
        sc.discipline='Mathematics'
```

The join will return exactly one row for each student,  either Student Name| Score or Student Name | NULL.  Coalesce then replaces the NULL with 'No Score'

Comment: Not tested the sytax on mysql (SQL Fiddle seems to be broken!) but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL RANK function and pick rows with rank value 1.
it should do the trick.
Check following link for details

[SQL Rank Function Detail Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)